# What is this the meaning of "Reload safe" web pages and can it be achieved with Ajax?

Tags: ajax, reload

1) I saw an interview question on this, and I'm assuming it's something to do with form submission and avoiding double submissions. Can someone confirm this?

2) Assuming this assumption is correct, can this be done with Ajax? If so is there a link someone can point me to?
(I'm assuming you'd generate some sort of random number and include it in the form as a hidden field, then ensure that number hadn't been submitted before for the session).

Comment: It was the J2EE Synchnronizer Token Design Pattern I was thinking about. I read about it in Erwin Vervaet's Spring Webflow book. See: http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip136.html

Answer (score 0):

[Redirect-after-post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) is a technique to avoid problems with the user refreshing or using the back button to get back to a posted form. In short, instead of providing a response page to an HTTP post, which will trigger another post if its reloaded, you issue a [303 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) (or a 302, to support ancient browsers by taking advantage of a bug that is as old as the web). This causes the browser to issue a second HTTP request - a get this time - and if the response page to that is reloaded there shouldn't be any problems. Just make sure that all the changes are made by the post handler and the page you redirect to has no side effects.

If you post using `XMLHttpRequest` then the redirect will be followed; unless you specifically support it using the [hash part of the location](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs) or the new [HTML5 history methods](http://html5demos.com/history) then the back button and reload aren't going to trigger an AJAX post again.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 1) 'the hash part of the location' or 2) The new HTML5 history method?

Comment: Also do you think Redirect after post is what they mean by "reload safe"?

Comment: I added links, and yes, I think Redirect-after-post is what is meant by "reload safe". Another question might be about bookmarkable links, and that where you need to use the location hash or the HTML5 history API.

Comment: right. Hash part of location is for bookmarkable content to reload the page to anchor points within the same document. A la Wiki pages and their Table of Contents. It puts the hash symbol at the end of the url...

Comment: I didn't quite understand the HTM5 example though from a quick scan of the source. Will have to dig around a bit more on that one. I think your take on the question derserves 1/2 marks. (Because I suspect Synchronizer Token may also be part of what was being asked).